# getting error if func is called (unrecognized selector sent to instance) swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uibutton, ios8.1

I created a function. This function is called by a button. If I press the button the app crashes and throws the following error:

`2014-12-23 18:42:59.966 MyApp[8775:115552] -[MyApp.ViewController setDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbbb9e458a0
2014-12-23 18:42:59.980 MyApp[8775:115552] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.ViewController setDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbbb9e458a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010451cf35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106060bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010452404d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010447c27c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010447be18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001049512b4 __NSFireTimer + 83
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104484f64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104484b25 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104447e5d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104447486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000106c289f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104da8420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    12  MyApp                               0x0000000103f6a08e top_level_code + 78
    13  MyApp                               0x0000000103f6a0ca main + 42
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107834145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

this is the function which is crashing if it's called:

```
func setDate(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        context.deleteObject(daten[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        daten.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        context.save(nil)

        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:

        let mySelectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        mySelectedCell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateLabel.text
        self.sideBar.alpha = 0

        return

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're attempting to call setDate without the proper parameters...

Comment: can you show how you are calling?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you have named this method wrong. Are you absolutly sure that it shouldn't be: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`?

Comment: Note that a method called `setDate`, with no trailing `:`, is very unusual.  Almost certainly an error at the call site, failing to provide the parameters.

Comment: How can I call this function without getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

This line tells you everything you need to know:

> -[MyApp.ViewController setDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbbb9e458a0

Your ViewController class doesn't have a method called `setDate` or a property called `date`.

As far as I can tell, the function you posted has nothing to do with this error. It never calls setDate.

Comment: It *is* setDate. But the OP's not calling it with the proper parameters apparently...

Comment: No, the method he posted is `setDate:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`. It is not `setDate`. There is a dramatic difference between the two.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: He/she's trying to call the method but apparently didn't include the parameters.

Comment: It's worse than that, the name of the method is `setDate:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` not `setDate`. (Note the lack of a colon in `setDate`. That is a method with no parameters at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm agreeing with that completely. I'm just disagreeing with this line that you wrote: "As far as I can tell, the function you posted has nothing to do with this error. It never calls setDate." since it's clear the OP was trying to call the posted function...so that's how it's related to the error.

Comment: I don't think it's so clear that the OP was trying to call that function. I don't think that function is named right (see my comment on the question itself,) and if I'm right about that, then the OP shouldn't be calling the function at all. I think the OP is so confused that (s)he isn't even asking the right question.

Comment: The OP says, "I created a function. This function is called by a button. If I press the button the app crashes and throws the following error:". So the OP's trying to call the function.

Comment: Not that all this back and forth matters... I think the basic issue is pretty clear in this case...that the OP's trying to call a function that doesn't exist...

Comment: Thanks for your answers! How can I call the function without a crash of the app?